# Simple question about parametric equations of a plane in 3D

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm quite rusty in Linear Algebra.

If you have a plane in 3D with the equation $z=2$, what does $x$ and $y$ equal? Does $x=t$ and $y=t$?

Because if I graph that in Wolfram Alpha, I don't get a horizontal plane in 3D at $z=2$: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+z%3D2%2Cx%3Dt%2Cy%3Dt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x, y$ can take on any value whatsoever, but they need not be equal. So if you insist on parameters for $x$ and $y$, you need separate parameters for each: $x = t, y = s$, with $t, s \in \mathbb R$.

So the points on the plane are simply of the form $(x, y, 2)$. Note that it suffices to express your plane as simply [$z = 2:$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z=2&a=*C.z-_*Variable-)

[image]

Comment: Adding nice graphics = +1

Answer (score 0):

The statement form “$z=2$” reads in words: “The third coordinate of a point equals two.”  Hence it's solution set consists of all points of the form $(\text{whatever}_1, \text{whatever}_2,2)$.  You'll make it from here.